# R system command for hive query

Tags: r, shell, hive

Because `rjdbc` and `hive2` not available for, Im using `system` command in R as below for running hive queries in local.

```
ret_text <- system(paste0("hive -S -e ","'", hql,"'"), wait = TRUE,intern=TRUE)
```

But the command gets formatted as below to send to `system`. Because of the extra single quotes the execution fails.

'hive -S -e 'INSERT INTO abc(col1,col2) values(1,'2019-01-11')''

ideally if it is like below it should work

"hive -S -e 'INSERT INTO abc(col1,col2) values(1,'2019-01-11')'"

(unable to format correctly as it involves quotes)

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve the issue by escaping the single quotes and using double quotes as below

```
  hql=gsub("'","\'",hql)
  ret_text <- system(paste0("hive -S -e ","\"", hql,"\""), wait = TRUE,intern=TRUE)
```

First escape all single quotes in the sql , And use double quotes to wrap the sql instead of single quotes(Escape wrapper double quotes too)